# Securely handling a couple of users' common information in Firebase's Firestore, red arrows under coupleId.contains(request.auth.uid)

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I need to store in Firebase informations about 2 users, that need to be properly secured against read by other users.

Example :

```
user1: 'Adam'
user2: 'Eve'
commonInfo:
    meetingDate: new Date(-600000,1,1)
    marriageDate: new Date(-300000,1,1)
    children:['users/Cain','users/Abel','users/Seth']
```

(I guess that Adam & Eve have bought a smartphone nowadays, who know who may use the app...)

The problem is that i need to secure Firebase in a simple and robust way.

I also need to take in account that one user may have several partner during his life.

**1/ Duplicate info**

My first idea was to use a cloud function to sync the data between the 2 user profiles.
The cloud function would run only if both partners have a "with:" targeting each other.

```
user1: 'Adam'
commonInfo:
    with: 'users/Eve' 
    meetingDate: new Date(-600000,1,1)
    marriageDate: new Date(-300000,1,1)
    children:['users/Cain','users/Abel','users/Seth']


user2: 'Eve'
commonInfo:
    with: 'users/Adam'
    meetingDate: new Date(-600000,1,1)
    marriageDate: new Date(-300000,1,1)
    children:['users/Cain','users/Abel','users/Seth']
```

Then the Firestore rule is dead simple:

```
match /users/{userId} {
      allow read, update, delete: if request.auth != null && request.auth.uid == userId;
      allow create: if request.auth != null;
    }
```

Yet I'm not very found of duplicating data...

**2/ Common document named afted users' ID**

It would be more economic to have a common document

```
couple:EveAdam
    meetingDate: new Date(-600000,1,1)
    marriageDate: new Date(-300000,1,1)
    children:['users/Cain','users/Abel','users/Seth']
```

I wrote this but I have 2 red arrows under coupleId and contains:

NB : contains used as per: https://github.com/google/cel-spec/blob/master/doc/langdef.md#list-of-standard-definitions

```
match /couples/{CoupleId} {
      allow read, update, delete: if request.auth != null && coupleId.contains(request.auth.uid);
      allow create: if request.auth != null;
    }
```

I'm new to firebase and have no idea if this will be working, neither if it is a good way to do that...

Comment: Security rules, by themselves, don't do anything at all.  It will be easier to think about them if you provide the specific client queries that should be allowed or rejected by the rules.

Comment: Also know that duplicating data is very common in nosql type databases.  You should come to expect that's the preferred option in many cases.

Comment: I believe that the best option would be to duplicate information, as it is a common practice in Firestore and other nosql databases as menitoned by Doug, and also that this `contains` logic is not possible to be done in the firebase rules in the way you are intending to do so you would have to probably keep both user ids separate in the documents themselves and that is also a kind of duplication once again. Let me know if this helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by @DougStevenson and myself on the comments the best approach would be to duplicate the data in more than one document for the following reasons:

- Data Duplication is a common and at times recommended practice for NoSQL databases.
- The second approach would no be possible with the current logic for `contains` in the firebase rules and the very fact that you are storing both uid concatenated is in itself a form of data duplication.